# How to get YouTube channel's trailer and featured video via the Data API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube Data API to get a channel's Trailer and Featured Video but can't find anything in the [API docs][1] or responses that might provide it. Ideally, there'd be something that would return the ID of whichever videos had been selected here: https://studio.youtube.com/channel/[CHANNEL_ID]/editing/sections

Maybe it's buried in an obscure endpoint. Maybe the API simply doesn't include this anywhere. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

---

Update: I've found the channel trailer as `unsubscribedTrailer` under the `channels:list` endpoint with the `brandingSettings` part. However, for some reason Google has decided not to include the featured video with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

As Video spotlight you can have:

> **Featured video for returning subscribers**
>
> Highlight a video for your subscribers to watch. This video won’t be shown again at the top of your page for subscribers who have watched it. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/youtube?p=customize_channel_layout)

Source: https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/editing/sections

For the featured video:

1. you first need to subscribe to the give YouTube channel. To do so in an automatic way, use YouTube Data API v3 [Subscriptions: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) endpoint.
2. then open your web-browser `Network` developer tool tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> on FireFox) and filter HTML requests, then visit https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID and copy the initial request to `CHANNEL_ID` as cURL, that way you can re-execute this cURL request for any channel you are subscribed to by changing the URL in the cURL request to https://www.youtube.com/channel/ANOTHER_CHANNEL_ID. Furthermore you'll find the featured video id in the JavaScript variable `ytInitialData` in the JSON entry
   `contents/twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer/tabs/0/tabRenderer/content/sectionListRenderer/contents/0/itemSectionRenderer/contents/0/channelFeaturedContentRenderer/items/0/videoRenderer/videoId`.

The channel with id [`UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ) have both a channel trailer ([`1RHxvM8mQS4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RHxvM8mQS4)) and a featured video ([`rFuip5CSWcA`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFuip5CSWcA)).